# Can string replacement be done without parsing?

Tags: algorithm

Its a straightforward question. Input: abc#ujk#o#p#l Output: abcujkopl
Can this be done in a time complexity of less than O(n)? Any algorithms that exist to do a faster removal?

Comment: simply iterate over the string, check if the current character is not `#` display it, else skip to the next character

Comment: Is the string to be removed always exactly one character?

Comment: You could build a machine to do this in O(1) **time**, but the algorithmic **time complexity** would still be O(n). The machine would simply have to do O(n) operations in parallel. In short, similar to the tradeoff between memory and time, you can trade hardware for time. That's exactly what a GPU does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think other answers are right in the specific case illustrated by your example. I'll attempt to generalize it.

Depending on your situation, there are multiple strategies. For instance:

*n: length of the string; m: the length of the pattern to be replaced*

1. naive O(n.m) search time with no processing time
2. O(n) search time with O(m) processing time
3. O(m) search time with O(n) processing time.

Algorithm 1 is not optimal in any case.

Algorithm 2 is useful if you do this task on many strings.

Algorithm 3 is useful if you do this task many times on a single string.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Single-pattern_algorithms for reference.

N.B. And of course, I did not even address the replacement task.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check entire string, all it's chars, so `O(n)` is the best possible time.

Answer (score 0):

This should be not done in a complexity less than O(n). Because you must iterate above every character of your input.

Here an interesting link I have found: [Sorting And Searching Algorithms - Time Complexities Cheat Sheet](https://www.hackerearth.com/de/practice/notes/sorting-and-searching-algorithms-time-complexities-cheat-sheet/).